# Switching from Ubuntu to Windows 10 without losing session

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, 19.10

I currently have Ubuntu 19.10 dual booting with Windows 10. Is there a way to switch from Ubuntu to Windows without losing my current Ubuntu session? i.e. I want my user account to remain logged in and all open windows and applications to retain their state.

I can do it the other way (Windows to Ubuntu) very easily, by going into Hibernate mode from Windows. This saves all active sessions on Windows (putting all logged in users in screen lock mode), and allows me to go to the OS selection screen when I wake up the computer.

Is there a way to do the same on Ubuntu?

**Note:** I'm not interested in running both OS's together. Switching between the two with saved sessions is enough. So, please don't suggest any virtualization ideas.

Comment: I am not sure whether this will help, but Ubuntu too has `suspend` feature. You can find it from dash. Not sure about the word they use for it, perhaps `sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

> I can do it the other way (Windows to Ubuntu) very easily, by going into Hibernate mode from Windows. This saves all active sessions on Windows (putting all logged in users in screen lock mode), and allows me to go to the OS selection screen when I wake up the computer.

There are two serious issues with that:

- There is a guaranteed loss of data if you are capable of changing anything on your windows disk from outside windows. The hibernation file will overwrite ANY changes you made. Writing to a hibernated Windows has been made impossible from Ubuntu by the creators of the Linux driver for NTFS with 1 exception: you can delete your hibernation file yourself. Result will be a loss of data on your windows partition.
- Anyone that comes in possession of your machine and/or has access to your machine can read out this hibernation file and/or access your information.

> Is there a way to do the same on Ubuntu?

The method for sessions was removed from the defaults of Ubuntu (or Linux in general) as it is considered a security breach. With that said and with accepting this: gnome 3 uses extensions. One of those is called [window session manager](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1323/window-session-manager/) and it will do what you want.

[image]

> Usage
>
> After a successful setup you should see an "screen" icon at your top bar. Click on it to open the menu. To save your first window session click on the text input and enter a name for it. Click on the save icon to save it.
>
> After this can either restore a previously saved session by clicking on the play icon, delete them by clicking on the x icon or update them by clicking on the save  .
>
> The opened applications and windows are saved independently for each screen combination, which means that you can have a different set of applications and arrangements for each of them and also need to save them independently.